# C# Winforms Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, outlook

I have a winforms application which works perfectly in my x64 Win 7 dev environment but I cannot get the Outlook feature to work at all on the x86 XP machine, I keep getting this error when I try to open up a new Outlook mail with the address/subject line pre-filled in from the application side.

[image]

This only started happening since adding the reference to: `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook`

This is the code used to create a new mail:

```
private void CreateOutlookEmail(string addresses)
        {
            Outlook.Application outlookApp = new Outlook.Application();
            Outlook.MailItem mailItem = (Outlook.MailItem)outlookApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
            mailItem.Subject = "";
            mailItem.To = addresses;
            mailItem.Body = "";
            mailItem.Display(false);
        }
```

I have been searching the forums for an answer but no luck thus far. Here is what I have tried without success:

- Set the platform target to x86 in project properties in VS2010
- Install the OWC11 binaries.
- Install all windows updates on the win XP machine.

Must I install other packs on the XP machine?

Comment: I beg your pardon for this but I need to ask. Did you have installed Office-Outlook on the target machine?

Comment: I think there is not Office installed on the target machine

Comment: Who down voted the OP please leaves some comment?

Comment: It is. Outlook opens up fine if I use the `mailto:` link in my winforms app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the [Primary Interop Assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15s06t57.aspx) on the system.  This happens automatically on your development system since they are installed with VisualStudio.  Other systems will not necessarily have them installed.

Better yet, you should probably be [deploying with an installer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386179.aspx) - this would take care of the dependencies for you.

---

[How to: Install Office Primary Interop Assemblies (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kh3965hw.aspx)

> [Microsoft Office 2010: Primary Interop Assemblies Redistributable (download)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3508)
>
> [2007 Microsoft Office System Update: Redistributable Primary Interop Assemblies (download)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18346)
>
> [Office 2003 Update: Redistributable Primary Interop Assemblies (download)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20923)

See Also :  [How to: Install the Visual Studio Tools for Office Runtime Redistributable (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178739.aspx)

---

Comment: Thanks. That is what was missing.